# independence of sum of independent random variables

Tags: probability

I want to know that if random variables X, Y, Z are independent, then are (X+Y) and Z independent?

I can solve $P(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\le x)=\frac{x^n}{n!}$ where $X_1,X_2, ...,X_n $ are independent random variables and each random variables is uniformly distributed on (0,1) by induction if it's right.

Comment: It is correct that if random variables $X, Y, Z$ are independent, then $X+Y$ and $Z$ are independent. Starting with pairwise independence would not be sufficient

Comment: Meanwhile you do not give a context for $P(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\le x)=\frac{x^n}{n!}$, but to be a cumulative distribution function it should be an increasing function of $x$ approaching $1$ as $x$ increases; that seems unlikely to me for $\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Comment: Could you show me why X+Y and Z are independent if X,Y,Z are independent?

Comment: If they are independent then knowing anything about $X$ and $Y$ tells you nothing about $Z$.  Knowing anything about $X+Y$ is knowing something about $X$ and $Y$, but since this tells you nothing about $Z$  you can conclude that    $X+Y$ and $Z$ are then also independent

Comment: With your edit to your question stating that the $X_i$ are i.i.d. uniform on $(0,1)$,  you are correct to say $P(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\le x)=\frac{x^n}{n!}$  when $0 \le x \le 1$ though not when $1 \lt x \le n$

Comment: In general, if $X_1, X_2 \cdots X_n$ are independent, then $Y=g(X_1, X_2 \cdots X_m)$ and $Z=h(X_{m+1} \cdots X_n)$ are independent.